# Xcode 3.2: Build & Analyze never finds any issues

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, clang, xcode3.2, clang-static-analyzer

I've used the Clang Static Analyzer from the command line before. I wanted to try Xcode's built-in version via Build & Analyze. I never get any negative results even though i specially prepared my code with very obvious issues Clang was always able to point out:

```
    // over-releasing an object:
    [label release];
    [label release];

    // uninitialized vars, allocating but not freeing an object
    NSString* str;
    int number;
    CCLabel* newLabel = [[CCLabel alloc] initWithString:str fontName:str fontSize:number];
    [newLabel setPosition:CGPointZero];
```

The result is always the same: a green checkbox, no issues.
I read that C++ code can cause issues. I'm running this with cocos2d that includes box2d. Could this be a cause? Did anyone get results from Build & Analyze with the cocos2d engine? What else could it be?

I also tried enabling the Static Analyzer Build Settings and then Build but the result was the same. I have restarted Xcode, cleaned all targets and emptied Xcode caches to no avail.

---

UPDATE: my issue could be caused by having added cocos2d as a cross-project reference to my project. Analyzing the cocos2d project itself seperately reveals some analyzer results.

In addition i found out that i get Analyzer results from my RELEASE build configurations but not from DEBUG builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Cocos2d and Box2d, and I get plenty of warnings from Build and Analyze.  Check to make sure your project's compiler is set to GCC 4.2 under "Compiler Version" in the Build Settings.

Comment: Actually it has to be set to "LLVM GCC 4.2" ... with that i'm getting analyze results! However, i also get a "can't exec" error precompiling the prefix header. I'll have to dig into that, maybe i need to update the LLVM GCC?

Comment: i realized i still had SDK 3.2 Seed installed, i'll re-install SDK 3.2 final and check if i forgot to install something because the "llvm-gcc-4.2" executable doesn't exist in my Xcode install

Comment: now i'm getting no results again ... argh. I think i'll just stick with the command line llvm gcc instead of wasting anymore time on this.

Comment: Did you clean all targets first?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that might come across this thread (and for the OP in case the problem persists):

I had this problem when building for the Simulator. However, switching to Device build got the Analyzer running.

This site might shed some more light on the issue: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/10/5/xcode-build-and-analyze-broken-for-simulator.html

Answer (score 0):

I also get plenty of Analyze warnings with my Cocos2d game.  I cleaned most of them up, but cocos2d 0.99.1 has 3 built-in!  (Which should be easily fixed.)

I have noticed that sometimes the analyzer doesn't find things unless I have that particular file open when I run it... go figure.

Comment: for a full analysis you have to run a clean build, otherwise the compiler won't analyze already compiled files