# What happened to XCode Build and Analyze results?

Tags: iphone, clang, xcode3.2

This is similar to another question that wasn't really answered: [Xcode 3.2: Build & Analyze never finds any issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738363/xcode-3-2-build-analyze-never-finds-any-issues)

I used XCode's Build and Analyze for the first time on a large project and came up with a number of analyzer warnings.  I corrected a few and wanted to verify my changes were being 'accepted' by the analyzer.  I didn't even look at warnings in a number of files.  But when I re-run Build and Analyze, all the warnings are gone.

I have tried: changing my compiler to LVVC GCC 4.2, switching from a debug to a release build, cleaning all (repeatedly), and quitting and reopening XCode.  I just can't get the old warnings back.

Comment: What’s in the build log (Cmd-Shift-B) after you clean all targets and run the analyzer?

Answer (score 1):

Build and analyze only analyzes your modified files.

Go to your project settings -> build tab. And check 'Run Static Analyzer'. This runs a full check on all files on each build.

Answer (score 0):

It is how XCode built with. Whenever, you build the project (even using build & analyze), it will build only those files which are modified before the last build. So if you want to have your old warning & analysis result back, do clean all targets from build menu & again build.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue some days ago. I had plenty of warnings, and after some changes in the code the analyzer warnings disappeared. Even a clean build could not bring them back.

By a coincidence I changed the message filter in the build log from `Issues Only` to `All messages`.
And there were plenty of messages related to the disappear of analyzer results. The analyzer complained that he could not analyze my files. I'm sorry I don't remember the correct message.

As far as I remember I put some code into the .pch which confused the analyzer completely.  After I changed a lot of stuff analyzer was happy again. Magically. I still don't know why that happened and I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, none of the solutions above worked for me.  The only way I could get the warnings back was to open the project with XCode 4 and analyze it there.  I am taking screenshots so I don't lose these warnings.  I hope the analyzer works better in XCode 4 in the future.